# how to make decision tree look nice in R and/or Jupyter?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, decision-tree, jupyter-irkernel

I'm very new to R, and decision trees in general, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to make a decision tree in R.  It's working, but when it does not look nice. It looks smushed.  I know it looks better when I expand the image, but it doesn't look good in Jupyter either.

Here's my code:

```
library(titanic)
library(party)
data("titanic_train")
surv_tree <- ctree(formula = as.factor(Survived) ~ as.factor(Pclass) + as.factor(Sex) + Age, data = titanic_train)
plot(surv_tree)
```

Here's a picture of what I mean:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/te0DM.jpg

I want to use rpart but it's not as accurate.  It's not treating "Pclass" as a categorical variable and it's annoying and inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to plot the tree on a bigger device (e.g., 8x16in):
[image: tree]

To be precise the plot above was created with `png(file = "tree.png", height = 8, width = 16, units = "in", res = 150)`. (Depending on which engine you use to create the figure on the fly, it might suffice to just set height/width.)

Additionally, you can tweak the font size via `plot(..., gp = gpar(fontsize = ...))`) if you use the new `partykit` implementation of `ctree()` as opposed to the old `party` implementation.

Finally, I would convert the factors in the data frame and not in the formula. Then the labels in the tree also look nicer:

```
titanic_train <- transform(titanic_train,
  Survived = factor(Survived),
  Pclass = factor(Pclass),
  Sex = factor(Sex)
)
plot(ctree(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age, data = titanic_train))
```